# How to display the first item of a combobox as a title of a combobox

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

What I wanted to do is make the first item of my combobox as a title. I tried to google and found out that I can use  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
but the problem is I have different controls that I hide and show based on Id.

xaml:
Lets say I have this in my xaml for combobox application

```
      <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,81" Width="122" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"   IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Applications}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValue="{Binding Path= SelectedApplication,Mode=TwoWay}"
         SelectedValuePath="Name" />
```

This is good until I get here  for combobox transaction

```
     <ComboBox Margin="0,0,732,81" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="124" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TransactionTypes}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValue="{Binding Path= SelectedTransaction,Mode=TwoWay}"
        SelectedValuePath="Name" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
```

Here since the first element is displayed by (IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" ) on the transaction combobox, my third control which is 
a grid which I want to display only when I do a select on the items
inside transaction is displayed by default but I don't want to load the grid on page load only when I do a select but again I want the title too.

Comment: When ComboBox loaded you can say combo.Text = combo.Items[0];

Comment: @Dilshod I am following MVVM and How do I do that in the viewmodel?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, there is no need for using the VM, since this is IMHO a view only matter. Simply bind the control to itself.

```
<!-- your settings are omitted, but you should keep them -->
<ComboBox Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
```

I'm a bit curious, that you're are using `SelectedValue`. Usually I'm using `SelectedItem`, but well may be there are several ways.